# 97 manual ford ranger throwing a camshaft position sensor code

Tags: ford, ranger, camshaft, timing, p0340

We've replaced the computer, sensor and timing belt(not sure of we did it right). Relays are good. Truck will fire, stay running for about 30 seconds then bog down & die

Comment: What is the exact code you're getting?

Comment: 03940 i believe

Comment: The code should start with a "P". A typical [Camshaft Position Sensor Circuit Malfunction](https://www.obd-codes.com/p0340) is P0340.

Comment: May want to note which engine is in the truck as well.

Comment: Yes that code..

Comment: 97 ford ranger 2.3L sorry guys

Comment: Can you confirm that the sensor has ignition voltage and ground? if you disconnect it, terminals one & three (harness side) should be ignition voltage (12+v) and ground. If you backprobe the second terminal (the signal out, do this while the engine is running and the sensor is plugged in) you'll see roughly half of ignition voltage. If you see only ignition voltage or ground on terminal 2, the sensor is either shorted to ground or the sensor to trigger wheel spacing is incorrect or the trigger wheel is broken/missing.

Comment: Also check the corrosponding pin at the PCM (computer) to ensure the signal is reaching the PCM with no voltage drop.

Comment: Theres only two wires not three

Comment: If it's a 2 wire sensor set your multimeter to Hz and probe the dark blue/org wire at idle it should be around 5-7 Hz. The other wire should be a ground that originates from the PCM and is connected to a bunch of other sensors.

Comment: Any ideas how i get to it to do that??

Comment: Ah you'd need a multimeter that has a hz setting. You could also set your multimeter to AC volts. I'm unsure of what reading you should be expecting, but I would assume if you get any reading out of the sensor than the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help i will try that then get back with the results

Comment: Anyone know the correct timing positions??

Answer (score 2):

P0340 is a Camshaft Sensor "A" Circuit Bank 1 code. This could be either a wiring issue, sensor failure, or camshaft/crankshaft timing issue.

Since you've replaced the timing belt, computer and sensor. I'd suggest you confirm sensor signal output at the sensor and at the computer. The two wire sensor produces a AC signal with an amplitude of roughly 4vAC with an average of 2.5vAC. The dark blue with orange stripe wire is the shielded signal wire, the gray with red strip wire is a common ground provided by the computer.

If you get the same readings at both the sensor and the corresponding computer pin than the wiring is OK. You can double check by doing a continuity test from the sensor to the computer.

To check the engine timing take a look at this image.

[image]

You can see that the camshaft mark (black triangle), oil pump sprocket mark (diamond) are lined up with a corresponding mark on the inner timing cover. While the crankshaft keyway is pointing at 12 o'clock.

If cam/crank timing is off make sure when you rerun the belt that the slack is on the tensioner side of the belt. Once you put tension on the belt rotate the engine by hand 720° or two revolutions and verify that the timing marks are lined up correctly.

Comment: Would the tensioner have anything to do with it throwing that code?

Comment: If you didn't have slack on the tension side of the belt when you installed the belt it can cause either the cam or crank to rotate as tension is applied. This may only be half a tooth. but usually it's enough to set a code. If there's too little tension on the belt it can cause the belt to slip.

Comment: If the truck doesn't stay running how am i able to check the voltage. It sounds like its only running on two cylinders but the only code that it throws is the camshaft sensor

Comment: pull the fuel pump fuse and have someone crank it while you check voltage at the sensor/computer.

Comment: Voltage in the computer?

Comment: I'd check sensor output at both the sensor and at the computer. this way you can eliminate a wiring issue if you see it at one place but not another.

Comment: So how do i check the computer?

Comment: it's... pin 85 on the computer connector same wire color. use a sewing pin or similar and backprobe the connector.

Comment: The timing positions are all on point so next thing is checking the wires

Comment: The blue wire went to 6 volts and the other wire went to 25 volts on the camshaft sensor?

Comment: Any idea what color the wire is for pin 85??

Comment: All the wires are good... Dont know what else to do...

Comment: @G.Travis Your probably going to need an oscilloscope if everything else checks out to verify the integrity of the ac waveform. another thing to check, maybe there's interference on the wire. make sure there isn't anything like plug wire leads or that the harness is routed along the alternator. make sure the shielding on the cam sensor wiring is still intact and check for loose grounds. if all else fails replace the cam sensor with a different part and if you haven't already put the original computer back in the car. Double check all the engine compartment fuses.